# R: enumerate column combinations of a matrix

Tags: r

(edit note: I changed the Title to "R: enumerate column combinations of a matrix", from "R grep: matching a matrix of strings to a list" to better reflect the solution)

I am trying to match a matrix of strings to a list: so that i can ultimately use the matrix as a map in later operations on a `data.frame`.

This first part works as intended, returning a list of all the possible pairs, triples and quad combinations (though perhaps this approach has created my bind?):

```
priceList <- data.frame(aaa = rnorm(100, 100, 10), bbb = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
            ccc = rnorm(100, 100, 10), ddd = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
            eee = rnorm(100, 100, 10), fff = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
            ggg = rnorm(100, 100, 10))

getTrades <- function(dd, Maxleg=3)
{
    nodes <- colnames(dd)
    tradeList <- list()
    for (i in 2:Maxleg){
        tradeLeg <- paste0('legs',i)
        tradeList[[tradeLeg]] <- combn(nodes, i)
    }
    return(tradeList)
}

tradeCombos <- getTrades(priceList, 4)
```

I'd now like to turn this list of possible combinations into trades. For example:

```
> tradeCombos[[1]][,1]
[1] "aaa" "bbb"
```

Needs to *eventually* become `priceList[,2] - priceList[,1]`, and so forth.

I have tried a few approaches with `grep` and similar commands, and feel that i've come close with the following:

```
LocList <- sapply(tradeCombos[[1]], regexpr, colnames(priceList))
```

However the format is not quite suitable for the next step.

Ideally, `LocList[1]` would return something like: `1 2`

Assuming that the `tradeCombos[[1]][,1] == "aaa" "bbb"`.

Can someone please help?

__

With help from all of the answers below, i've now got:

```
colDiff <- function(x) 
{
    Reduce('-', rev(x))
}

getTrades <- function(dd, Maxleg=3)
{
    tradeList <- list()
    for (i in 2:Maxleg){
        tradeLeg <- paste0('legs',i)
        tradeLegsList <- combn(names(dd), i, 
            function(x) dd[x], simplify = FALSE)
        nameMtx <- combn(names(dd), i)
        names(tradeLegsList) <- apply(nameMtx, MARGIN=2, 
            FUN=function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse='*'))
        tradeList[[tradeLeg]] <- lapply(tradeLegsList, colDiff) 
    }
    return(tradeList)
}

tradeCombos <- getTrades(priceList, 4)
```

This retains the names of the constitutent parts, and is everything I was trying to achieve.

Many thanks to all for the help.

Comment: By the way, get familiar with `combn`! Try `combn(names(priceList, 2))`, or `combn(names(priceList, 3))` and see what you come up with.

Comment: @mrdwab, i am basically using `combn(names(priceList), 3)` in the `getTrades` function, with `tradeList[[tradeLeg]] <- combn(nodes, i)`.  Looking below, however, it's clear that i have a LOT to learn about `combn`. thanks very much for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets your eventual aim using `lapply`, `apply`, and `Reduce`.

```
lapply(tradeCombos, 
 function(combos) 
 apply(combos, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(combo) Reduce('-', priceList[rev(combo)])))
```

`combo` is a column from one of the combo matrices in `tradeCombos`. `rev(combo)` reverses the column so the last value is first. The `R` syntax for selecting a subset of columns from a `data.frame` is `DF[col.names]`, so `priceList[rev(combo)]` is a subset of `priceList` with just the columns in `combo`, in reverse order. `data.frame`s are actually just `list`s of columns, so any function that's designed to iterate over `list`s can be used to iterate over the columns in a `data.frame`. `Reduce` is one such function. `Reduce` takes a function (in this case the subtract function `-`) and a `list` of arguments and then successively calls the function on the arguments in the `list` with the results of the previous call, e.g., (((arg1 - arg2) - arg3) - arg4).

You rename the columns in `tradeCombos` so that the final column names reflect their source with:

```
tradeCombos <- lapply(tradeCombos, 
    function(combos) {
        dimnames(combos)[[2]] <- apply(combos, 
            MARGIN=2, 
            FUN=function(combo) paste(rev(combo), collapse='-')
        )
        return(combos)
    }
)
```

Comment: +1, thanks - very useful. I was unaware of a number of these possibilities.  Is it possible to make the column names of the matrices attached to each list location reflect the names of the columns used in their constuction?

Comment: `apply` carries over the column names of its argument. see my edits for a way to rename the columns in `tradeCombos`

Comment: no, you got it mate. you have solved all of my problems. Cannot ask for more than that - so i switched the accepted. Everyone that has answered has been wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

### Whoa... ignore everything below and jump to the update

As mentioned in my comment, you can just use `combn`. This solution doesn't take you to your very last step, but instead, creates a list of `data.frames`. From there, it is easy to use `lapply` to get to whatever your final step would be.

Here's the simplified function:

```
TradeCombos <- function(dd, MaxLeg) {
  combos = combn(names(dd), MaxLeg)
  apply(combos, 2, function(x) dd[x])
}
```

To use it, just specify your dataset and the number of combinations you're looking for.

```
TradeCombos(priceList, 3)
TradeCombos(priceList, 4)
```

---

Moving on: @mplourde has shown you how to use `Reduce` to successively subtract. A similar approach would be taken here:

```
cumDiff <- function(x) Reduce("-", rev(x))
lapply(TradeCombos(priceList, 3), cumDiff)
```

By keeping the output of the `TradeCombos` function as a `list` of `data.frame`s, you'll be leaving more room for flexibility. For instance, if you wanted row sums, you can simply use `lapply(TradeCombos(priceList, 3), rowSums)`; similar approaches can be taken for whatever function you want to apply.

## Update

I'm not sure why @GSee didn't add this as an answer, but I think it's pretty awesome:

Get your `list` of `data.frame`s as follows:

```
combn(names(priceList), 3, function(x) priceList[x], simplify = FALSE)
```

Advance as needed. (For example, using the `cumDiff` function we created: `combn(names(priceList), 2, function(x) cumDiff(priceList[x]), simplify = FALSE)`.)

Comment: Did you know that `combn` accepts a `FUN` argument?  i.e. you don't really need the `apply`

Comment: @GSee, I didn't, but that's ***awesome***. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @GSee, can I transfer it to you somehow :-)

Comment: Don't sell yourself short. `combn` is doing the work whether you feed it `FUN` or not.

Comment: +1 & accepted. thanks, i learnt a lot from this answer. Much appreciated. The missing bit - but i'm working on it - it retaining the colnames - so i can see how each vector in the output is constituted.

Comment: What do you mean, the column names are there!

Comment: @mnel i guess the problem was a result of how i had used the above insights. The function as i was updating it (see the Qn above) did not return the names. I required the help of mplourde's update to complete my task - which is why i gave him the accept. his solution best solved the exact problem i had.

Answer (score 1):

`tradeCombos` is a `list` with `matrix` elements. Therefore, `tradeCombos[[1]]` is a `matrix` for which `apply` is more suitable.

```
apply(tradeCombos[[1]],1,function(x) match(x,names(priceList)))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    1    3
 [3,]    1    4
 [4,]    1    5
 [5,]    1    6
 [6,]    1    7
 [7,]    2    3
 [8,]    2    4
 [9,]    2    5
[10,]    2    6
[11,]    2    7
[12,]    3    4
[13,]    3    5
[14,]    3    6
[15,]    3    7
[16,]    4    5
[17,]    4    6
[18,]    4    7
[19,]    5    6
[20,]    5    7
[21,]    6    7
```

Incidentally, you can subset using the string form anyway, eg `priceList[,"aaa"]`

Comment: +1, thanks. that's exactly the answer to the question i originally asked (and thought i needed to solve).  Combining your answer with your incidental insight yielded `apply(tradeCombos[[1]], 2, function(x) priceList[x])`, which is _extremely_ useful.

Comment: atually, after a little playing i changed a line of the getTrades function to the following: `tradeList[[tradeLeg]] <- apply(combn(colnames(dd), i), 2, function(x) dd[x])`