# Passing multiple arguments to Reduce

Tags: r, reduce

I have a list of data.frames, and would like to operate on their columns, using various weights.

For example, subtracting the first columns from the second column (solved, see below); or subtracting the first and third from twice the second (unsolved).

Thanks to the generous help obtained in response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368674/r-enumerate-column-combinations-of-a-matrix) question, I have a solution to the the problem in two dimensions without weights using `Reduce`.

I would like to have the flexibility to operate with weights - and in higher dimesions.

What I have so far is:

```
priceList <- data.frame(aaa = rnorm(100, 100, 10), bbb = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
                        ccc = rnorm(100, 100, 10), ddd = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
                        eee = rnorm(100, 100, 10), fff = rnorm(100, 100, 10), 
                        ggg = rnorm(100, 100, 10)
                        )

colDiff <- function(x) 
    {
        Reduce('-', rev(x))
    }

tradeLegsList <- combn(names(priceList), 3, function(x) priceList[x], simplify = FALSE)

tradeList <- lapply(tradeLegsList, colDiff)
```

From what I can tell, `Reduce` is not designed to take multiple arguments.

I can do this the long way with `2* tradeLegsList[[1]]$bbb - tradeLegsList[[1]]$aaa - tradeLegsList[[1]]$ccc`, and some loops, but it doesn't seem like *the R way*.

Is there a way to pass in a weight vector?

Ideally, I would to pass an argument such as `w = c(-1, 2, -1)` to the `colDiff` (or `Reduce`) function ... or something similar.

Comment: If your data is like in your example, i.e. all `numeric` and each list element has the same dimensions, then I would highly recommend you store your data in a 3d array. Then what you are trying to do can be done in a one-liner with `%*%` (matrix multiplication) and possibly `aperm`.

Comment: Yes, that is how the data will look once it is prepared. Thanks, i will investigate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True, `Reduce` is not geared to allow multiple arguments, just two for each reduction. Therefore  it is easiest to premultiply the elements in the list you are `Reduce`-ing.

Below is a solution that does this using `mapply` within your `colDiff` function definition.

Change your definifion of colDiff to allow a weight vector, and apply this using `mapply`
 with `SIMPLIFY = F`.

## EDIT

In light of the comments, weighting depends on the  number of columns and there being no need for the `rev`

The weighting by length

> length(x) == 1 -> w = 1
>   length(x) == 2 -> w = c(-1, 1),
>   length(x) == 3 -> w = c(-1, 2, -1),
>   length(x) == 4 -> w = c(-1, 1, -1, +1)

```
weighting <- function(i){
  switch(i, 1, c(-1,1), c(-1,2,-1), c(-1,1,-1, 1))
}
colDiff <- function(x) 
    {
        w = weighting(length(x))
        Reduce('+', mapply('*', x, e2 = w, SIMPLIFY = F))
    }
```

Then something like this would work

```
tradeList <- lapply(tradeLegsList, colDiff)
```

you could also keep with the functional programming theme and use `Map` which is a simple wrapper for `mapply` with `SIMPLIFY = F`

```
colDiff <- function(x) 
        {
            w = weighting(length(x))
            Reduce('+', Map('*', x , e2 = w))
        }
```

you could also prefine the weighting within the function colDiff (which may be easier). 
`weighting[[2]]` is weighting for when there are 2 columns, `weighting[[3]]` when there are 3.

```
colDiff <- function(x) 
        {
         weighting <- list(1, c(-1,1), c(-1,2,-1), c(-1,1,-1, 1))             
            w = weighting[[length(x)]]
            Reduce('+', Map('*', x , e2 = w))
        }
```

Comment: +1, thanks. I think you need to change the sign on the operation in the `Reduce` statment. ie, make the `Reduce('-', ...`, `Reduce('+', ...` ... but that breaks the `w = NULL` case ... maybe `e2 = -w`?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. If one of your tradeLegList elements is a data.frame with columns `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`. The function should will give `-ccc - 2bbb - aaa` if `w = c(-1,2,1)`. (given that you reversed the order of x within the Reduce call

Comment: Apologies. The desired outcome from `w = c(-1, 2, -1)` is `-aaa +2bbb -ccc`. Do you think the full solution is to write a function that turns the weights appropriate order such that we can use `+` in `Replace`?

Comment: Then yes, `+` is the way to go. Why did you have `rev(x)` in the original?

Comment: Do the weights depend on the names of the columns? If so the solution can be changed to accomodate this.

Comment: The rev(x) in the original was there as we didn't have weights, so were using `-` and `Reduce`. The weights will eventually come from a seperate step, and be passed in - however the default weights _ideally_ would depend on `length(x)` ... with `length(x) == 2` -> `w = c(-1, 1)`, `length(x) == 3` -> `w = c(-1, 2, -1)`, `length(x) == 4` -> `w = c(-1, 1, -1, +1)`. I've done this with a bunch of nested `if`s, but given your form i'm sure you have three better ways :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16577/discussion-between-mnel-and-ricardo)

Comment: I've adjusted the solution to allow for weighting depending (on a predefined way) on the number of columns